# Open port 443 for a node web app

Tags: nodejs, webapp-development

I've been trying to run a node web app on port 443 but I'm getting this output Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443

Already tried ufw  allow 443/tcp but nmap is still not showing 443 as an open port.

Also tried sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT w/ no success.

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Check whether the same port is used by another app. since 80 and 443 will be default used by some application. Try changing port and check

Answer (score 10):

Thanx @exore, I solved the issue with

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(readlink -f $(which node))
```

The problem was, I believe, a manual installation of node.js. It comes as default on Ubuntu's last version but I didn't knew that and I installed it again through terminal.

You can go here for the entire discussion.

https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6389682

Regards,

Comment: Wow. That worked. Why? And should this be the solution for a production app?

Answer (score 1):

EACCES means it is forbidden to listen on port 443. This is because you're not running your app as `root`. Ports below 1024 are reserved ports, and only `root` may use them.

Trying to change the firewall rules will have no effect, as firewalls let packets go through or stop them. They do not allow someone to listen to any particular port.

Solution : run your code with `sudo`, but this may be a security risk. So your app should switch to another user (or find some other mechanism I am not aware of to drop privileges) as soon as possible, just after the successful listen.

Since this is complicated, a good solution is

1. your app listen on the `loopback` interface on a non privileged port, say for example `127.0.0.1:10443`
2. You setup a webserver to proxy requests from `0:443` to `127.0.0.1:10443`. nginx come to mind but many other servers are usable for this task. Just pick your favorite one.

If you want SSL on port 443, which is usually the case, you should also set up certificates (create a self signed one or buy one or better still, get a free certificate from let's encrypt), configure protocols, available ciphers etc... This is also complicated.

Example minimal nginx config file that needs improvement and should work (can't test right now):

```
server {
    server_name  me.example.com;
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/mycerts/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/mycerts/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 30m;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:400k;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    server_tokens off;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:10443/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use sudo npm run start:dev :D

Comment: Can you explain how this will resolve the question of running the site through port 443? 